# Pycharm 3.4 won't run on Yosemite

Tags: java, pycharm, osx-yosemite

Pycharm 3.4 (fresh install) will not run on Yosemite with Apple JDK 1.6:

```
Crashed Thread:        32  Java: AWT-EventQueue-0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _CGContextSetAllowsAcceleration
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libawt.jnilib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
```

There are advices to switch to Oracle JDK 1.7 but since apple 1.6 is recommended I would rather stick with that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to download and install a fresh update for Apple Java 1.6. At the moment the latest update was [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

Answer (score 12):

Edit this file: /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/Info.plist

> vi /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/Info.plist

**CHANGE:**

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.6*</string>
```

**TO:**

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.8*</string>
```

Is this it

Comment: I tried your suggestion and PyCharm starts but all the fonts are strange. It looks terrible over all. So, I uninstalled Java8 and installed Java 6 from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572. Now PyCharm starts and it looks nice also.

Comment: In some cases you must use 1.7*

Comment: I'd just rather not have unpatch-able, ancient java anywhere on my system. Haven't noticed font or other irregularities after pointing to 1.8+, even works with python3.4 and django 1.7/selenium installed via pip3 

Answer (score 3):

For PyCharm 4 in Mac OS X Yosemite:

- Edit /Applications/[PyCharm app name]/Contents/Info.plist
- Find and Replace -

this

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
    <string>1.6*</string>
```

with

```
 <key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.8*</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Install [Java 6 from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

From the [Jetbrains Blog](https://jetbrains.zendesk.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks):

> Modifying Info.plist will break the application digital signature and prevent the patch updates. We do not recommend modifying Info.plist file to run under JDK 1.7 or 1.8.
>
> Current JDK 1.7 and 1.8 versions have several critical issues. We can't default to the new JDK version until these issues are resolved

Comment: That post is from late 2013, and tracked old versions of both java and JetBrains products, and Apple's Java 1.6 hasn't been patched since May 2014. Since the info.plist fix is working I'm rolling with it for now.